# mount.cifs ignores `user` and `username`

Tags: mount, cifs

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ...

I am trying to mount a share from a netgear readyNAS ultra 6.

I installed the `cifs-utils` package and I am trying to run:

```
sudo mount.cifs '\\nas1.local\sharename' '/mnt/nas1_sharename` -o domain=mydomain username=useronnas1
```

but when prompting me for a password it asks about:

```
password for current_unix_username@\\nas1.local\sharename:
```

ignoring the `username=useronnas1` option.

I am trying also:

```
sudo mount.cifs '\\nas1.local\sharename' '/mnt/nas1_sharename` -o domain=mydomain -o username=useronnas1
```

OR

```
sudo mount.cifs '\\nas1.local\sharename' '/mnt/nas1_sharename` -o domain=mydomain,username=useronnas1
```

both seem to get the user properly.

Now however I get:

```
mount error(95): operation not supported
```

but this is a new and another issue.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

o.k. found it.
I should use either:

```
sudo mount.cifs '\\nas1.local\sharename' '/mnt/nas1_sharename` -o domain=mydomain -o username=useronnas1
```

or

```
sudo mount.cifs '\\nas1.local\sharename' '/mnt/nas1_sharename` -o domain=mydomain,username=useronnas1
```

both seem to get the user properly.

Now however I get:

```
mount error(95): operation not supported
```

but this is a new and another issue.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have installed `cifs-utils`, read [Mount password
  protected network folders](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Mount_password_protected_network_folders)
- Else, read [Mount Windows Shares Permanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

Right format of an `user` option is:

> ```
> user=arg
> ```
>
> where `arg` specifies the username to connect to Windows Share. If this is not
>   given, then the environment variable `USER` is used. This option can
>   also take the form `user%password` or `workgroup/user` or
>   `workgroup/user%password` to allow the password and workgroup **to be
>   specified** as part of the username.